# Is it possible to get the token transfers of a address?

Tags: etherscan

I want to get token transfers of an address (incoming) but i guess once i have this sorted i can figure that out.

So for example here - https://etherscan.io/address/0x3f5ce5fbfe3e9af3971dd833d26ba9b5c936f0be#tokentxns

They have all the token transfers and i can't really see in their API to get all the token transfers so i was wondering if anyone knew how to do to get all token transfers going on the address.
I have tried doing many stuff while trying to using web3.js and try subscribe to events.
I realise when a smart contract transfers a token the Transfer event is called and emitted but i don't see how to show all the token transfers using etherscan API.
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use etherscan API, you can use https://etherscan.io/apis#logs.

However, you'll have to know contract addresses of all tokens that you wish to watch.

The Transfer event for ERC20 is defined as

```
event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
```

That means:

- topic0 will be the hash of the signature of the event itself
- topic1 will be the address of the sender
- topic2 will be the address of the receiver

For orientation, you can look into the logs in the transaction receipt of a transfer transaction. -> e.g. https://etherscan.io/tx/0x5c354e4f25f2da8ee608c445cad43c171bc553859dd787fc0800a904344a7ecd#eventlog

Comment: How does etherscan do it though?
I want to get all token transfers..? and i don't know all the contract addresses ;/

Comment: They have the complete chain. Most probably also with indexed data in their own database. This way it's easy to compile a list of all ERC20 contract instances. If you wish that too, you'll have to setup own node, make a full sync and parse through the transactions and transaction receipts (which include the logs).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do it like this: https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=logs&action=getLogs&fromBlock=0&toBlock=latest&topic0=0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef&topic2=0x000000000000000000000000001c356c0be5dd6c91ca24ef04d9e10081510682

Here `topic2` parameter specifies the address (padded to 256 bits) to get all incoming token transfers for.

Here is an example of result record:

```
{ "address":"0x2155877da05c52368b830bfd56e96405a2668d8b", // Token smart contract
  "topics":[ 
    "0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef",
    "0x000000000000000000000000a67d0d44eee2a6ed2081a6f50bb59dd41df3c554", // From
    "0x000000000000000000000000001c356c0be5dd6c91ca24ef04d9e10081510682"], // To
  "data":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e8", // Amount
  "blockNumber":"0x57ca63",
  "timeStamp":"0x5b1a7e82",
  "gasPrice":"0x28fa6ae00",
  "gasUsed":"0x14ca6",
  "logIndex":"0x30", 
  "transactionHash":"0x523ae8fbb7db6103cd7f821896a6f6a5a830cbc63d980a44760459633b80e24f",
  "transactionIndex":"0x8a"}
```